# How to use Linux Kernel

Tags: linux, java

I would like to build a very small and simple operating system that runs java application on top of Linux kernel just like android, just to improve my knowledge and to build some hands on experience on how to leverage Linux kernel.

I have downloaded the latest Linux kernel from kernel.org. and i now wanted to deploy a Java JVM on top on the kernel and would like to Run some java applications.

Would anyone please help me to do this... I have been trying to do this...

Answer (score 0):

"Linux From Scratch" and "Beyond Linux From Scratch" will teach you step-by-step how to build your own distro but your best bet is to just use an already existing distro and just have your users install everything as an appliance. For example, F5 LTM is based on CentOS and the LTM functionality is just something they've built using java/tomcat and miscellaneous small-ish executables.

Building your own distro for an actual project is probably overkill unless you're actually trying to achieve some particular purpose that all existing distros make impossible or impractical.